# Getting the number of letters from a word

Tags: c#

New to c# here. I've made a list of cities, possible travelling destinations.

```
enum Destination {Rome, London, Tokyo, Istanbul, Miami};
```

Now I need something that will determine the price for each ticket having that the price is: number of letters in each city * 1000. I don't really know how to get the number of letters from the cities and converting them to an integer. Or maybe there is a better way to represent the cities?

Comment: I've tried looking at the enumerated cities as strings than converting them to an integer, but didn't quite work out.

Comment: If the list of cities is likely to change, then don't store them as an `enum`. Instead, just make a list of `string`.

Comment: or in VS 2015 `nameof(Destination.Tokyo).Length * 1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sampleDestination = Destination.Tokyo;
var destinationAsString = sampleDestination.ToString();
var numberOfLetters = destinationAsString.Length;
var cost = numberOfLetters * 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert the value to string and call the `Count()` method. Like this - `Destination.Istanbul.ToString().Count()`.